# Remove zsh autocomplete suggestion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, prezto

When I type

```
cd l
```

and hit tab, zsh autocompletes to

```
cd lightdm/
```

this is not a directory that is available to me (in fact I've uninstalled lightdm).

How do I stop this from happening?

I have prezto installed.

https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the combination of the `AUTO_NAME_DIRS` and `CDABLE_VARS` options documented in `zshoptions(1)`.

```
% PS1='%# ' zsh -f
% setopt AUTO_NAME_DIRS
% setopt CDABLE_VARS
% autoload -U compinit
% compinit
% cd a        # was mashing tab here to no avail (nor asdf)
cd: no such file or directory: a
% hash -d asdf=/etc
% cd asdf/    # "cd a" now tab completes
```

(This was discovered by searching `zshoptions` for "dir" and "cd" related strings.)

To turn this off disable one or more of those options (`unsetopt`) or remove the variable(s) that the completion code is finding.

Answer (score 1):

As user `thrig` has already mentioned in his answer, this was caused by `CDABLE_VARS` option being set.

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding

`unsetopt CDABLE_VARS`

line to my `.zshrc`

Comment: I see --- as clear as thrig's answer was, I was not able to follow it until I saw yours.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up looking into `.zhistory` and deleting all references to `lightdm` this solved the problem for me. There maybe be other places zsh stores completions, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: This is totally bogus -- and didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me after clearing the erroneous entries in `.zsh_history`, and then restarting my terminal.