# How can I prevent zsh from trying to autocomplete URLs?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

The default completion of the `curl` and `open` commands tries to fill in URLs. For example, typing `curl <TAB>` gives

```
file:    ftp://    gopher://    http://    https://
```

alongside any files in the current directory.

I never want to autocomplete URLs, so these suggestions are just visual noise mixed in with the filenames etc. that I’m actually interested in. How can I prevent zsh from offering URL completion for a particular command? How can I prevent it from offering this for *any* command?

Comment: Take a Look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469320/remove-zsh-autocomplete-suggestion

Comment: @ss_iwe I don’t believe that applies in my case… Zsh doesn’t think those things are directories; it knows they’re URLs. (And I don’t have `CDABLE_VARS` set anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in [a 2011 post by Mikael Magnusson](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00692.html) to the zsh users mailing list.

To prevent zsh from ever trying to autocomplete URLs for the `open` command, run

```
zstyle ':completion:*:open:argument*' tag-order - '! urls'
```

I believe you can do this for all commands, not just `open`, by saying

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:argument*' tag-order - '! urls'
```

If you want to disable URL autocompletion most of the time, but allow it when the current directory is empty, run

```
zstyle ':completion:*:open:argument*' tag-order '! urls'
```